# Prove that if two triangles are in perspective centrally, they are in perspective axially.

Tags: geometry

> $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ are two triangles such that $AA'$, $BB'$, and $CC'$ meet at $O$. Prove that if $BC$ and $B'C'$ meet at $L$, $CA$ and $C'A'$ meet at $M$, and $AB$ and $A'B'$ meet at $N$, then $L$, $M$, and $N$ are collinear.

[image: diagram]

My approach:

Applying Menelaus theorem to $\triangle ABC$ and transversal $P-K-L$ we get $$\frac{CP}{PA} \frac{AK}{KB} \frac{BL}{LC} = 1$$ (Considering only lengths, not directions)

Similarly for transversal $G-H-M$ we get $$\frac{BG}{GC}\frac{CM}{MA}\frac{AH}{HB} = 1$$ and for transversal $J-I-N$ we have $$\frac{BJ}{JC}\frac{CI}{IA}\frac{AN}{NB} = 1$$ Now multiplying these equations we get $$\overbrace{\color{blue}{\frac{BL}{LC}\frac{CM}{MA}\frac{AN}{NB}}}^\text{converse of Menelaus theorem for L-M-N}\color{red}{\frac{CP}{PA} \frac{AK}{KB} \frac{BG}{GC}\frac{AH}{HB}\frac{BJ}{JC}\frac{CI}{IA}} = 1$$

Now, if I can prove that the red part equals 1 then the question is solved. But I am unable to do so. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Desargues's theorem. It holds for any projective space defined arithmetically from a [division ring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring). However, it is possible to construct planes in which this proposition is false. These planes even [have a name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Desarguesian_plane).

As the above suggests, Desargues's theorem is true for the [real projective plane](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane), which is the space we're concerned with. [This article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem) features a three-dimensional proof. Here is a simpler proof, hoping that you are familiar with [projective transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography):

Let $P$ be a projective transformation that sends $MN$ to the line at infinity. Since $P$ preserves incidence, it is sufficient to prove the proposition under the assumption that $MN$ is the line at infinity. By [Thales's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), $CC'$ passes through $O$ if and only if $BC \parallel B'C'$, that is, $L$ is an infinite point. $\blacksquare$